# SQL SUM values by DISTINCT column after JOIN

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

I've been searching the forums for a solution for hours now but I couldn't quite find the one that is fitting for my problem.

I have two tables:

```
members
****************
id   name    city
1    John    Boston
2    Maria   Boston
3    Steve   London
4    Oscar   London
5    Ben     Singapore

donations
********************
member_id    amount
1            100
1            150 
2            300 
3            50
3            100
3            50
4            75
5            200
```

I'm trying to create an aggregated list of donations by cities. So I should get the sum of each members' donations and sum that by each city.

So my end result should be something like this:

```
Result
*************
Boston    550
London    275
Singapore 200
```

This is the latest version of my query:

```
SELECT me.id, me.city, don.mySUM
   FROM members me
LEFT JOIN (SELECT member_id, SUM(amount) AS mySUM 
   FROM donations GROUP BY member_id) don 
ON don.member_id=me.id GROUP BY me.city ORDER BY mySUM DESC
```

But it's obviously missing something because it aggregates the cities but only adds the sum of one users donations.

Could anybody please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no donation information of a city then donation column will show null. To convert it to 0 you can use `coalesce(SUM(d.amount),0)`.

Schema and insert statements:

```
create table members(id int,   name varchar(50),    city varchar(50));
insert into members values(1,    'John'    ,'Boston');
insert into members values(2,    'Maria'   ,'Boston');
insert into members values(3,    'Steve'   ,'London');
insert into members values(4,    'Oscar'   ,'London');
insert into members values(5,    'Ben'     ,'Singapore');

create table donations(member_id int,    amount int);
insert into donations values(1,            100);
insert into donations values(1,            150); 
insert into donations values(2,            300 );
insert into donations values(3,            50);
insert into donations values(3,            100);
insert into donations values(3,            50);
insert into donations values(4,            75);
insert into donations values(5,            200);
```

Query:

```
SELECT m.city, SUM(d.amount) as donations
FROM members m LEFT JOIN
     donations d
     ON d.member_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.city
ORDER BY city;
```

Output:

| city | total_donations |
| --- | --- |
| Boston | 550 |
| London | 275 |
| Singapore | 200 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=715056dcd374647d8cd27a5fd4e207ad)*

Comment: @Zoltan you are most welcome. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `join` and `group by`.  You are overcomplicating things:

```
SELECT m.city, SUM(d.amount) as total_donations
FROM members me LEFT JOIN
     donations d
     ON d.member_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.city
ORDER BY total_donations DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would implement the `join`. Assuming your `left join` was intentional, when summing numeric quantities, I typically use `coalesce` to show `0` for `nulls`, but consider it optional for your purpose.

```
select a.city, sum(coalesce(b.amount,0)) as total_amount
from members a 
left join donations b on a.member_id=b.id
group by a.city
order by total_amount desc;
```

Comment: Thank you Phil! In my case the result doesn't show nulls only 0, but thanks for your input, I'll keep coalesce in mind in case a need it.